# Where do I find LongListSelectorItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have installed the latest version of WPtoolkit through NuGet.

By browsing the code on CodePlex it looks as if it should be available: http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336040

Comment: I can see longlistmultiselector for win8, are you targeting a specific version?

Comment: I got LongListMultiSelector aswell. I'm targeting Windows Phone 8.
It's the LongListSelectorItem I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's under default `<phone> </phone>` namespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

For Reference see this too
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something but I can only find the LongListSelector in in the phone namespace, not the LongListSelectorItem. What I try to achieve is to change the template of the item I selected so I assume I would need the container of the SelectedItem.